# Making NERDTree work 'as expected'

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to be able to `o` or double click on a file in NERDTree, and have it open in a split to the right, and have NERDTree stay open. I haven't found the magic dust to sprinkle on my .vimrc to make this happen yet, can anyone help?

I'd want to to behave like any GUI text editor, where the explorer persists and the files open and close in the 'main pane'.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Some more information about your `.vimrc` will probably be needed. My default NERDTree install behaves exactly as you describe - even double-clicking on files to open them, which I hadn't tried before. No fairy dust needed.

Comment: Hmm. I thought I was pretty vanilla; when I get back to work I can re-post tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this in your `.vimrc`:

```
:let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 0
```

I find the following mappings useful:

```
nnoremap <Leader>d :let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1<bar>NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>D :let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 0<bar>NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

So `\d` opens a NERDTree that closes on file selection, while `\D` opens a persistent/pinned NERDTree.

Comment: Bingo, that did it. So the takehome rule is when learning/setting up vim, never blindly take someone else's settings as your own. Best to put the lines in one by one to build up the program how you want it. :-)

Comment: Hm. For some reason the NERDTreeQuitOnOpen does not seem to work for me.

Comment: `vim Documents/` after pressing `o` to open a file from the directory, NERDTree gets closed. So basically adding the setting into a config file doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

By putting the following lines in your .vimrc config will open NERDTree automatically when vim starts up on opening a directory `vim ReactProjectFolder` and prevent NERDTree from hiding when first selecting a file

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | wincmd p | ene | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | endif
```

Taken from the [nerdtree f.a.q](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/wiki/F.A.Q.#how-can-i-open-nerdtree-automatically-when-vim-starts-up-on-opening-a-directory)